# Exception when reading Parquet files having BINARY channels

Tags: arrays, parquet

I am getting Parquet decoding exception which is caused by ArrayOutOfBound exception when reading a parquet file with BINARY channels. I am able to read parquet files if it does not contain BINARY fields.
 The piece of code that involves the array out of bound exception is:

```
public Binary readBytes() {

    try {

      int length = BytesUtils.readIntLittleEndian(in, offset);
      int start = offset + 4;
      offset = start + length;
      return Binary.fromConstantByteArray(in, start, length);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new ParquetDecodingException("could not read bytes at offset " + offset, e);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      throw new ParquetDecodingException("could not read bytes at offset " + offset, e);
    }
  }
```

The function readIntLittleEndian(in, offset) is as follows:

```
public static int readIntLittleEndian(byte[] in, int offset) throws IOException {

    int ch4 = in[offset] & 0xff;
    int ch3 = in[offset + 1] & 0xff;
    int ch2 = in[offset + 2] & 0xff;
    int ch1 = in[offset + 3] & 0xff;
    return ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));
  }
```

These methods are part of parquet-hadoop jar file from apache.

Here is the detailed exception message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 7032 in block 0 in file file:/C:/Users/EKE9FE/Documents/MATLAB/part-0
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:243)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader.read(ParquetReader.java:125)
    at parquet.compat.test.ConvertUtils$1.next(ConvertUtils.java:439)
    at parquet.compat.test.ConvertUtils$1.next(ConvertUtils.java:1)
    at parquet.compat.test.ConvertUtils.getFullParquetFile(ConvertUtils.java:63)
    at parquet.compat.test.Test.main(Test.java:35)

Caused by: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can't read value in column [B_avfra] BINARY at value 7032 out of 7724, 7032 out of 7724 in currentPage. repetition level: 0, definition level: 0
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.readValue(ColumnReaderImpl.java:483)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.writeCurrentValueToConverter(ColumnReaderImpl.java:370)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.RecordReaderImplementation.read(RecordReaderImplementation.java:405)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:218)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: could not read bytes at offset 28124
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.plain.BinaryPlainValuesReader.readBytes(BinaryPlainValuesReader.java:46)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl$2$6.read(ColumnReaderImpl.java:312)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.readValue(ColumnReaderImpl.java:464)
    ... 8 more

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 28124
    at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesUtils.readIntLittleEndian(BytesUtils.java:57)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.plain.BinaryPlainValuesReader.readBytes(BinaryPlainValuesReader.java:39)
    ... 10 more
```